# Passing array into React stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pure-function

Following example from book Learn ReactJS, my attempt to pass an array in the same manner only yields errors.

From the Github examples by authors: https://github.com/MoonHighway/learning-react/blob/master/chapter-04/03-react-components/04-components.html

```
 const IngredientsList = ({items}) =>
        React.createElement("ul", {className: "ingredients"},
            items.map((ingredient, i) =>
                React.createElement("li", { key: i }, ingredient)
            )
        )
    const items = [
        "1 lb Salmon",
        "1 cup Pine Nuts",
        "2 cups Butter Lettuce",
        "1 Yellow Squash",
        "1/2 cup Olive Oil",
        "3 cloves of Garlic"
    ]
    ReactDOM.render(
      React.createElement(IngredientsList, {items}, null),
      document.getElementById('react-container')
    )
```

I stood up a React app with `create-react-app`, and wrote the following in App.js:

```
const things = [
    'foo',
    'bar',
    'baz',
    'fizz',
    'buzz'
];

const App = ({things}) =>
    React.createElement("ul",{className: "thingsAndStuff"},
    things.map((item, value) =>
        React.createElement("li", {key:value}, item)
        )
    );
```

In index.js I had ReactDom.render as:

```
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App, null, null), document.getElementById('root'));
```

I received an error "things.map not a function".
When I removed the destructured `things` (`const App = () => ...`), my component worked.

My questions are:
    1. How is `things` being pulled into App() when both were declared with `const` and conceivably not in the same scope, and `things` is not specifically being passed into the function?
    2. Would the example code have worked for me had I done something different?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *props* are passed into a component when using `createElement`:

```
  React.createElement(App, /*props:*/ { things });
```

The first snippet does that. The second does not, and therefore the local variable `things` will be `undefined`, and therefore you can't iterate over it. If you want to access a global variable, you just have to make sure that no local variable has the same name, so this would also work:

```
const App = () => React.createElement("ul",
     { className: "thingsAndStuff" },
     things.map((item, value) =>
        React.createElement("li", {key:value}, item)
     )
);
```